# Android Notification from server

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-service

My problem statement is as follows :-

I have developed Client-Server model based Application . now to Notify client for a event there may be two scenarios :-

1. if client is connected to server then send notification by sending data through the connected Socket.
2. if client is not connected then I am sending a message to client using Android's android.telephony.SmsMessage and at the client end a broadcast receiver to receive this message.

Now I want to know if there is some other way to send notification using Internet connection(data connection) . I have a solution ,to create a service which connects to the server whenever user turn on data connection and listens for notification but i think it will eat up extra resources.

I want to know how facebook or whatsApp sends notification to their users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first started to program for android. I also thought to do Client-Server model but it is a very complex model to implement in android. There is something else called GCM (Google Cloud Messagning ) Service, which is used by all these big giants and by me (Small giant). Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html). With GCM you don´t need to be connected to client all the time. You can just send message to the client and client recieves it whenever the client has access to internet.

Comment: Hi Dusean thanks for the link
I implemented this model pretty well so far , as I developed Server in c++ which is handling clients very well .i want to provide notification facility to my clients(android)  like Facebook and whatsApp .

Comment: Then you want to use GCM as suggested here.  Using Client Server for notifications is problematic, battery draining and memory draining.  GCM is what WhatsApp and Facebook use.